# Tracking google ad to purchase

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am struggling with tracking my google ads to point of purchase. I want to track a google ad that is linked to a page on my site that gives details about the product. Then I want the tracking to follow them after they click the purchase now button to where they check out in my shopify store.

I have been reading up on cutom urls, etc. but this tracking is by far my weakest area and not a strength of mine. It just is not making sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring too is called Conversion Tracking in Adwords which

> is a free tool that shows you what happens after a customer clicks on your ads

You are going to want to get started [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722022?hl=en) first so you can understand what it is.

Then when you are ready head on over to [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095821) to learn how to set it up for your website. There is a button on that page labeled "Guide Me" which will help you get set it up. It will literally give your arrows where you are the click in the process.

Eventually you will get the tracking code for your conversion "Goal" that you are tracking which in your case is someone buying a product from your site after clicking an ad.

It will instruct you to place the code on your site to the page that the ad points too in between the `<body></body>` tags of the page.

All of this process so far involves Google Adwords. If you want to track to the point of purchase this will involve adding a similar Goal Tracking with Google Analytics to follow the user all the way to a customer purchasing a product.

What might be leaving you confused is how to track the user all the way to purchase once they click on the ad that points to your site...well this is how you do it.

For each ad you have in adwords you are going to want to create a specific page that is for that ad only. Don't point it to your homepage or any regular page for that matter on your site. Create a new page tailored for that ad. The reason you do this is so that you know anyone who visits that page came from an ad. If you want to get more specific you can also create different pages for different ads so you can track and see which ads perform the best to reaching your goal of a purchase.

If you do not already have a [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) account you are going to want to set one up and start using it. It's awesome.

Once you setup your account head on over to [here](https://thrivethemes.com/conversion-tracking-google-analytics/). This will teach you how to setup a goal with Google analytics. This works similar to the way Adwords works where you will get a tracking code from GA as well that you will place on the page that finalizes your goal. What I mean by that is once a purchase is made I am sure the user is redirected to some kind of page that confirms the purchase. That is the page where you place the code so that you know the Goal/Conversion was made.

Once you have placed the code, GA will track your goal for you and let you know how many users reached your goal.

Hope this help you.